# Webcam Image Update in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, refresh

I am having major brain ache on this one. I have a webcam that i snap an image from every 5 seconds. I have read all of the comments and I can successfully display an image from the webcam but cannot get the image to update. I have read the similar posts and tried everything.
Am i missing something?

This is what I have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  <title>Webcam</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var x = 0;

    function init() {
      window.onmessage = (event) => {
        if (event.data) {
          var ImageURL = document.getElementById("webcam1");

          ImageURL.src = event.data;

          Clear();

          function Clear() {
            document.getElementById("Load").style.display = "None";
            document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML = "Clearing";
            setInterval(UpdateImage, 20000);

            function UpdateImage() {
              x = x + 1;

              var temp = ImageURL.src;
              UpdatedImageURL.src = temp + "?=t" + new Date().getTime();
              var UpdatedImageURL = document.getElementById("webcam1");
              document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML =
                "Updating .... " + x;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
  <p id="Load">Loading ....</p>
  <p id="Test">Starting ....</p>
  <img id="webcam1" alt=" " width="700" height="450" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: don't confuse [java with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: Your right, sorry.